# Undergraduate math books with a "plot"

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I usually have trouble trying to read huge tomes without any proper motivation - there's no feeling that I'm "working" towards something. Perhaps I've been spoiled by "Abel's Theorem through Problems and Solutions" by V.B Alekseev which builds up group theory solely to prove the insolubility of the quintic, but it was nice knowing there was something "big" at the end of it all. I'm looking for books in a similar vein, that might focus on a single question and build a story around it.

Comment: Yeah, I study for math for the plot

Comment: Sounds cool! I think Elliptic Tales is a similar book that culminates in the BSD conjecture

Comment: I think [Borevich & Shafarevich Number Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Number-Theory-Pure-Applied-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00EJQM10I) is such a book, sadly out of print but there are copies out there.  Starts by citing versions of the Weil conjectures, then goes into number theoretic topics.  You don't get all the way to a proof of the conjectures though.

Comment: [Serre's Course in Arithmetic](https://www.amazon.com/Course-Arithmetic-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387900403) is another.  Short, but very densely written. Covers a lot of ground.